# JQuery input type file upload validation IE problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have eventually figured out how to validate files selected with the input file element.  What I do is check the file type and if it matches the extension I want then I return it to a text box, if it doesn't I trigger the input file element again.

The problem is the IE 9/10 triggers the input file element the first time but not the second time.  FireFox works like a charm.

```
<input type="file" id="fleTest2" style="display: none;">
<input type="text" id="txbText2" style="cursor: pointer;" readonly="readonly">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#txbText2').click(function() {
            $(this).blur();
            $('#fleTest2').trigger('click');
        });
        $('#fleTest2').change(function() {
            var vals = $(this).val(), val = vals.length ? vals.split('\\').pop() : '';
            var filetype = vals.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            if ($.inArray(filetype, ['txt']) == -1) {
                alert('Please select only text files');
                $(this).click();
            } else {
                $('#txbText2').val(val).blur();
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
$('#fleTest2').trigger('click');
```

to this:

```
$('#fleTest2').trigger('change'); //<---use change not click
```

You have to trigger `change` as you have bound this *`change`* event to the element, so you have to trigger it. Yet if you use `.on()` method to bind multiple events then you can trigger the `click` event:

```
$('#fleTest2').on('change click', function() {
```

then you can trigger `click` too:

```
$('#fleTest2').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Thanks Jai.  That is not the part I am having a problem with.  It is in the if statement where the problem is.  After I check the file selected.